# Android Studio ADB filtering for apps doesn't work anymore

Tags: filter, android-studio, adb, filtering

The ADB still works and recognizes my device correctly and if I select "Not Filter" it displays all debug messages.

However when I select the app I am working on it filters all messages out and leaves nothing for me to see.

How can I fix this and repair filtering for specified apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the location of the adb.exe to the PATH variable in Windows resolved the issue.

Comment: What if I'm on a Mac? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry mate, but unfortunately for you I don't know anything about Mac.

Answer (score 1):

to people, which need the answer for Linux.
Just do it.

```
Tools -> Android -> [Check] Enable ADB Intergration
```

[source](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73560)

Regards.